# Could not find driver using MySQL database in PhpStorm

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, when trying to access the database from the web, **Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver** pops out. When testing connection in Data Sources and Drivers, driver is shown and connection is OK.

I removed the uncommented the `extension=pdo_mysql` in php.ini file. When running it from the console, works fine.

Comment: *"When testing connection in Data Sources and Drivers, driver is shown and connection is OK."* This is irrelevant here: "Data Sources" uses JDBC drivers (Java specific) to talk to the DB (and is used by the IDE itself only). What happens in PHP is to be sorted in PHP only.

Comment: *"In PhpStorm, when trying to access the database from the web..."* Need to know the details: what web server is used to serve your web pages. What URL is used? If it's Apache -- have you restarted Apache so the PHP can see the changes in php.ini? If it's PhpStorm's built-in simple web server, have you restarted PhpStorm (so it can load the web server anew with a fresh config)?